# Explanation of store variable in fat arrow middleware example from Idiomatic Redux tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand some javascript syntax I saw on the very well done `Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux`  video https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-applying-redux-middleware

```
const promise = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (typeof action.then === 'function') {
        return action.then(next)
    }
    return (action)
}
```

an example usage call in the video is

```
middleware(store)(store.dispatch)
```

Now I don't see `store` being used anywhere in the scope of the inner most function. Can someone explain the purpose of passing in `store`?

Comment: it's just an example. store has methods `getState`, `dispatch`, `subscribe` so technically you could do something with that. getting the current state and doing something with that is pretty common like logging / autosaving etc.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks @azium. if you'd like to paste that in as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.